# Gson not assignig value to direct inner object but it assigns values if I use array

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have an interesting situation with my project, I am using retrofit2 with rxjava2 in my android project. This is the builder for retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

This the method definition in api interface

```
@GET("get_config")
Observable<ConfigResoponse > getConfig(@Query("version") Float mVersion);
```

App is not working for this scenario when direct object is used

Json response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "test_version": 1.1,
        "test_data": "{\"project_name\": \"mytestproj\",\"min_sdk_version\": 1.0}"
    },
    "version": 1.0
}
```

POJO for response

```
public class ConfigResoponse {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("version")
@Expose
private Float version;

//getter and setters

class Data {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("test_version")
@Expose
private Float testVersion;
@SerializedName("test_data")
@Expose
private String testData;

//getter and setters for data class
}
```

this is how I am calling the method

```
apiService.getConfig(mVersion).subscribe(new Observer<ConfigResoponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    System.out.println("on subscribe ConfigResoponse ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(final ConfigResoponse configResponse) {
                    if(configResponse.getData() != null) {
                    //error occurs here if I try to access below statement
                    configResponse.getData().getTestVersion();
                }
```

If I change data to `List<>` instead of direct object this works.

Changed json that works

```
{
        "success": true,
        "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "test_version": 1.1,
            "test_data": "{\"project_name\": \"mytestproj\",\"min_sdk_version\": 1.0}"
        }],
        "version": 1.0
    }
```

Changed POJO for response

```
public class ConfigResoponse {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Data> data = null;
@SerializedName("version")
@Expose
private Float version;

public Boolean getSuccess() {
return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
this.success = success;
}

public List<Data> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Data> data) {
this.data = data;
}

public Float getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(Float version) {
this.version = version;
}

public class Data {

      @SerializedName("id")
      @Expose
      private Integer id;
      @SerializedName("test_version")
      @Expose
      private Float testVersion;
      @SerializedName("test_data")
      @Expose
      private String testData;

      public Integer getId() {
          return id;
      }

      public void setId(Integer id) {
          this.id = id;
      }

      public Float getTestVersion() {
           return testVersion;
      }

      public void setTestVersion(Float testVersion) {
         this.testVersion = testVersion;
      }

      public String getTestData() {
        return testData;
      }

      public void setTestData(String testData) {
         this.testData = testData;
      }

    }
}
```

StackTrace for error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
2019-12-18 11:42:27.531 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at com.myapp.mylib.e0.f.a$a.a(Unknown Source:3)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.531 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at com.myapp.mylib.o$a.a(DataManager.java:159)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.532 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at com.myapp.mylib.o$a.a(DataManager.java:144)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.532 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at f.a.r.e.c.e$a.a(ObservableOnErrorNext.java:68)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.533 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at f.a.r.e.c.d$a.d(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.533 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at f.a.r.e.c.d$a.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.534 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at f.a.o.b.b$b.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.535 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.535 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.536 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.536 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7285)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.537 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.537 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
2019-12-18 11:42:27.537 22101-22101/com.mycomp.demoapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

This is a library module and the same thing with direct object is working with another project.

Comment: post data class as well

Comment: I have defined data class as inner class of response, already posted.

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting similar response from server what you have posted as JSON response? check whether response from server is not as `"data" : [...]`

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier the same code is working if I add library module in other project.

Comment: @ShadowDroid I've checked the response and its what is expected.

Comment: @karan in new json you posted it clearly evident that json has array of data i.e. `"data" : [..]` so how would you expect it to parse asJSONObject  instead of JSONArray. Also by not working means you might be getting error so post log/stacktrace of that as well.

Comment: @karan thanks for adding extra info - it does look like the original code should parse the original json; and it makes sense that the new code parses the new json. I agree with Shadow Droid that you should be analysing the error/stacktrace.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier what is confusing me is that the same thing is working when I am including it library module in another project. I have updated the code and tried to capture the null. but object is not null and when I try to access the value of id the app is crashing with NPE.

Comment: You should show which code relates to the stack trace (maybe deobfuscate the stack trace too). The edit #6 that you made suggests that it can't crash where you are saying it does crash.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier how to deobfuscate as shrinking and proguard both are disabled?

Comment: The stack trace definitely looks obfuscated. That stack trace should tell us where the error happened. That info might help you.

Comment: remove expose and add only SerializedName and add if(null != configResponse && configResponse.getData() != null)

Comment: and are you getting response in other objects or not.?